# simple program output does not appear anymore in command window after python upgrade

Tags: environment-variables, output, stdout

I have been running simple programs with python3.4 without trouble, directly typing the program name (without the .py extension) from a command shell, in the directory where the python scripts are located. The expected output would then appear in the shell, and upon termination of the program the next prompt appears, as expected. I recently upgraded to 3.6.4 to develop more complex applications using NumPy and pandas. since the upgrade however, running the same programs still work (e.g.,  I can see the tk windows appear and behave as before), but the next prompt immediately appear in the command window while the program is still running, and the expected output from simple print statements is redirected somewhere (where?). On another hand, running the program by typing 'python program_name.py' rather than just 'program_name' works as before, with the output appearing in the command window as expected. what configuration settings could have been present with 3.4.0 and missing with 3.6.4 that would explain those discrepancies? Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any errors while running those programs? Also, what version of Python were you using before the update?

Comment: Hi Adam, there is no change aside from the missing output. The GUI is working fine, the expected files are still written, just missing all the statements expected in stdout.

Comment: it worked fine with 3.4.0 and a very basic implementation, virtually no additional library installed aside from tk.

Comment: Just posted about Python 2 vs Python 3 but that isn't the problem then.

Comment: Just found out that typing 'python program_name.py' in the command window rather than just 'program_name' as before works just fine. So what is the setup or configuration parameter I am now missing?

Comment: Do you have the shebang at the first line of the script?

Comment: yes, the shebang is here